# angularjs $rootScope.on() TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`myApp.run(['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope ) {
  console.log($rootScope);
  $rootScope.on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {});
}]);`

Here in console I am getting output as scope object but on next line I am getting error as Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function....

Comment: Try `console.log($rootScrope.on)` to get an idea whether you're passing the right thing

Comment: `$rootScope.$on` (Note the second `$`)

Comment: Thanks @JAAulde....it worked.....now blocked on retrieving the value added in this. I can see value assigned in object from console.log() but not able to retrieve it..